# cssSelector throwing error in selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

The following lines of code is giving me error:

```
elem = new Array()
elem = driver.findElements(By.CssSelector('input'));
```

What's wrong in the above statement?

If I have a HTML form like:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="/login_check">
   <input type="hidden" value="" name="_csrf_token">
   <div class="form-group">
      <input id="username" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Email:" required="required" value="sfdgvsgsg" name="_username">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input id="password" class="form-control input-lg" type="password" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Password:" required="required" name="_password">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <input id="_submit" class="btn submit" type="submit" value="LOGIN" name="_submit">
   </div>
</form>
```

And I use a script like this:

```
elem = new Array()
elem = driver.findElements(By.CssSelector('input:required'));
```

Then also I am getting the same error.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\testPhantomJS\node_modules\selenium-webdriver>mocha -t 80000 tes
tMocha/login-as-administrator-mocha.js


  TrackRevenue Test
    1) Login as Administrator


  0 passing (29s)
  1 failing

  1) TrackRevenue Test Login as Administrator:
     TypeError: undefined is not a function
      at Array.forEach (native)
```

#### EDIT:

As requested, I am presenting my whole code:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var By = webdriver.By;
var until = webdriver.until;
var equals = webdriver.equals;

/*----login details for Administrator----*/
var userAdmin = '';
var passAdmin = 'DarkPrince2012';
/*---------------------------------------*/

/*-----------extra details---------------*/
var baseUrl = 'http://saswatr3.ouh.co/login';
var expectedTitle = "Track Revenue";
var successMessage = "Welcome to the admin page!";
/*---------------------------------------*/

test.describe('TrackRevenue Test', function() 
{
  test.it('Login as Administrator', function() 
  {
        var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
                    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox())
                    .build();
        var loginFlag = 0;
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.getTitle().then(function(title) 
        {
            if(expectedTitle === title)
            {


                driver.findElement(By.id('username')).sendKeys(userAdmin);
                driver.findElement(By.id('password')).sendKeys(passAdmin);
                driver.findElement(By.id('_submit')).click();
                driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input:required")).then(function(elem){
                console.log(elem.length);
                });
                driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Log out')]")).then(function(elements_arr)
                {
                    if(elements_arr.length > 0)
                    {
                        loginFlag = 1;
                        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'user-name m-r-sm text-muted welcome-message')]")).getAttribute("innerText").then(function(text){
                                   console.log("Logged in as : " + text);
                                });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Invalid credentials.')]")).then(function(elements_arr2)
                        {
                           if(elements_arr2.length > 0)
                                console.log("Login Unsuccessful, div invalid credentials found");
                           else
                                console.log("Login Unsuccessful, div invalid credentials not found");
                        });
                    } 
                    if(loginFlag == 1)
                        console.log("Login Successful");
                    else
                        console.log("Login Unsuccessful");
                });
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("Verification Failed - An incorrect title is displayed on the web page.");
            }
        });

    driver.quit();
  });
});
```

#### What I want to achieve:

See this section:

```
driver.findElement(By.id('username')).sendKeys(userAdmin);
driver.findElement(By.id('password')).sendKeys(passAdmin);
driver.findElement(By.id('_submit')).click();
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input:required")).then(function(elem){
                    console.log(elem.length);
                    });
```

As you can compare with the HTML form, when the submit button is clicked, the HTML5 validation is checked. If any of the two inputs are blank, then the HTML% validation throws a message.

I want to check that HTML5 validation message in the selenium script. If no validation message is thrown, the form is presumed submitted.

The problem I am facing is, neither I can detect the HTML5 validation, and after the

```
driver.findElement(By.id('_submit')).click();
```

the form is getting submitted.

Comment: Judging by the error I don't think it has anything to do with either of your selectors. Both selectors are valid anyway.

Comment: Is it problem with phantomJS?

Comment: Do I need to import any other libraries for this?

Comment: can you post more of your code after the findElements line? there might lie the problem

Comment: @drkthng, I am posting my whole code. And I will explain something more too.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting type error because you are using invalid locator tag. Change `CssSelector` to `cssSelector` in your code above, it should fix your problem.

```
elem = new Array()
elem = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector('input'));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish with this CSS Selector?

```
"input:required"
```

Are you trying to get the INPUTs with the required attribute? If so, try this

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[required]"))
```

If not, please explain more clearly what you are trying to do.